# SELECT row if certain field is NOT null. Else, select row with null field instead

Tags: mysql

I'm having a hard time solving my sql problem. Would like to select a row if a certain field(LOOKUP) is not null. Else, get the row with the null field instead. Please see table below:
(PAYCODE must be unique)

| PAYCODE | LOOKUP | ACCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | null | 720001 |
| 201 | 659057 | 999999 |
| 202 | null | 720002 |

The output must be:

| PAYCODE | LOOKUP | ACCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 659057 | 999999 |
| 202 | null | 720002 |

This looks so easy but I am new to sql and solving this for 2 days while searching for solutions but no luck.

Comment: If there is another row with `PAYCODE = 201` and `LOOKUP = 65656565`, will it be included to the output?

Comment: Why is `999999` chosen over `720001` ?

Comment: Had you tried to use `MAX`?

Comment: yes I have tried MAX already. 720001 is chosen because LOOKUP column is not null for PAYCODE 201

Comment: @arsho no. table is designed to have only one LOOKUP that is not null so it can't have another LOOKUP where LOOKUP = 65656565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following logic:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE LOOKUP IS NOT NULL OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.PAYCODE = t1.PAYCODE AND
                        t2.LOOKUP IS NOT NULL);
```

### Demo

This logic retains any record whose `LOOKUP` is not null or any record for which there is no non null record having the same `PAYCODE`.

Comment: Hi @Tim, Just tried this sql again but found out that 
PAYCODE 202 is not showing. I want to select it also if there is no other PAYCODE 202 available :) Tried also EXISTS but it is not working

Comment: @Gelo It is working, at least on your sample data, [see the demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec6d8e2d013eae6c3f0eb9cd0ae14d62).